# How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, escaping, character, sql-like

I am trying to filter items with a [stored procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure) using *like*. The column is a varchar(15). The items I am trying to filter have square brackets in the name.

For example:  `WC[R]S123456`.

If I do a `LIKE 'WC[R]S123456'` it will not return anything.

I found some information on using the `ESCAPE` keyword with `LIKE`, but how can I use it to treat the square brackets as a regular string?

Answer (score 414, accepted):

```
LIKE 'WC[[]R]S123456'
```

or

```
LIKE 'WC\[R]S123456' ESCAPE '\'
```

Should work.

Comment: The ESCAPE keyword is required if you want to use a custom escape character (the backslash is indeed custom).

Comment: I corrected the other part of the answer too. [SQL Fiddle with before and after versions](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5633)

Comment: note if you want to find open then close bracket, the [[] []] won't work, you have to use the ESCAPE '\' method.

Comment: If anyone is unclear as to why the bracket needs to be escaped, the [documentation for LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) indicates it is used to match a single character in a range or set. For example, using `LIKE '[fz]oo'` will match both 'foo' and 'zoo'.

Comment: It would be nice to have rationale for both of these in the answer. It was not immediately obvious to me why the first example would work until I read the answer from Amitesh below.

Comment: Prefer `LIKE 'WC\[R]S123456' ESCAPE '\'` as it is more readable for maintenance.

Comment: I've found that some versions of SQL or variants don't allow the ESCAPE keyword, while others don't allow the `[*]` selection. I've had to use both in my code.

Comment: For me, it looks like, the first proposal would match WC[S123456 or WC]S123456 or WCRS123456. So exactly one of the characters in the brackets would match. It is not the expected result. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15#using-wildcard-characters-as-literals

Answer (score 159):

Let's say you want to match the literal `its[brac]et`.

You don't need to escape the `]` as it has special meaning only when it is paired with `[`.

**Therefore escaping `[` suffices to solve the problem.** You can escape `[` *by replacing it with* `[[]`.

Comment: `[[]` does look weird, but it makes sense when you look at it from the perspective of the parser.  The parser has a specific rule for how to handle characters between `[ ]`.  So, the text `its[brac]et` means: _"Find the following consecutive strings: `its`, (apply rule for square brackets: `brac`), `et`"_.  On the other hand, `its[[]brac]et` means: _"Find the following consecutive strings: `its`, (apply rule for square brackets: `[`), `brac]et`"_.

Answer (score 30):

I needed to exclude names that started with an underscore from a query, so I ended up with this:

```
WHERE b.[name] not like '\_%' escape '\'  -- use \ as the escape character
```

Comment: I had to use this version (specifying the "escape" character explicitly) - the other answers here didn't give the correct results for me.

Answer (score 23):

Here is what I actually used:

```
like 'WC![R]S123456' ESCAPE '!'
```

Answer (score 19):

The ESCAPE keyword is used if you need to search for special characters like % and _, which are normally wild cards. If you specify ESCAPE, SQL will search literally for the characters % and _.

[Here's a good article with some more examples](http://search400.techtarget.com/tip/1,289483,sid3_gci870464,00.html)

```
SELECT columns FROM table WHERE 
    column LIKE '%[[]SQL Server Driver]%' 

-- or 

SELECT columns FROM table WHERE 
    column LIKE '%\[SQL Server Driver]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 7):

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql):

> You can use the wildcard pattern matching characters as literal
>   characters. To use a wildcard character as a literal character,
>   enclose the wildcard character in brackets.

You need to escape these three characters `%_[`:

```
'5%'      LIKE '5[%]'      -- true
'5$'      LIKE '5[%]'      -- false
'foo_bar' LIKE 'foo[_]bar' -- true
'foo$bar' LIKE 'foo[_]bar' -- false
'foo[bar' LIKE 'foo[[]bar' -- true
'foo]bar' LIKE 'foo]bar'   -- true
```

Answer (score 6):

If you would need to escape special characters like **'_'** (underscore), as it was in my case, and you are not willing/not able to define an ESCAPE clause, you may wish to enclose the special character with square brackets **'['** and **']'**.

This explains the meaning of the "weird" string **'[[]'** - it just embraces the **'['** character with square brackets, effectively escaping it.

My use case was to specify the name of a stored procedure with underscores in it as a filter criteria for the Profiler. So I've put string **'%name[_]of[_]a[_]stored[_]procedure%'** in a TextData LIKE field and it gave me trace results I wanted to achieve.

Here is a good example from the documentation:
[LIKE (Transact-SQL) - Using Wildcard Characters As Literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx#Anchor_7)

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem in that while

```
LIKE 'WC[[]R]S123456'
```

and

```
LIKE 'WC\[R]S123456' ESCAPE '\'
```

both work for SQL Server, neither work for [Oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Database).

It seems that there isn't any ISO/IEC 9075 way to recognize a pattern involving a left brace.

Comment: Brace: `{`  
Bracket: `[`  
Parenthesis: `(`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of '\' or another character on the keyboard, you can also use special characters that aren't on the keyboard. Depending o your use case this might be necessary, if you don't want user input to accidentally be used as an escape character.

Comment: I often use `¬` - it's still a keyboard character in the UK but rarely used knowingly :) (top left between `Esc` and `Tab` )

Comment: Users can still submit data containing letters which aren’t on the keyboard. This answer sounds suspiciously like a suggestion to avoid actually solving the problem…

Answer (score 0):

**Use the following.**

For user input to search as it is, use escape, in that it will require the following replacement for all special characters (the below covers all of SQL Server).

Here a single quote, "'" ,is not taken as it does not affect the *like* clause as it is a matter of string concatenation.

The "-" & "^" & "]" replace is not required as we are escaping "[".

```
String FormattedString = "UserString".Replace("ð","ðð").Replace("_", "ð_").Replace("%", "ð%").Replace("[", "ð[");
```

Then, in SQL Query it should be as following. (In parameterised query, the string can be added with patterns after the above replacement).

To search an exact string.

```
like 'FormattedString' ESCAPE 'ð'
```

To search *start with a string*:

```
like '%FormattedString' ESCAPE 'ð'
```

To search *end with a string*:

```
like 'FormattedString%' ESCAPE 'ð'
```

To search *containing with a string*:

```
like '%FormattedString%' ESCAPE 'ð'
```

And so on for other pattern matching. But direct user input needs to be formatted as mentioned above.