# How to escape a string for use with the LIKE operator in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching

I am looking for something that works in SQL Server similar to the `@` symbol in c# which causes a string to be taken as it's literal.  Eg:

```
string text = "abcd\\efg";
Output of text = abcd\efg

string text = @"abcd\\efg";
Output of text = abcd\\efg
```

Note how the @ affected the string to take every character as is.

Now I am not sure this is possible but here is my issue and maybe there is a better way to solve this.  Consider the following basic query:

```
SELECT [Name] 
  FROM [Test] 
 WHERE [Name] LIKE (@searchText + '%')
```

My issue is if they put a `%`, `_` or any other of those special characters that can affect my like clause.  I want the match to act just like a 'starts with' function.  So is there anything I can apply to the @searchText to say take this literally or is there possbibly a better solution that I am not thinking of?

**Edit:** I do not want the solution to be client side cleaning.  I need this stored proc to work without relying on the data being passed in being cleaned.

Comment: To avoid confusion, the issue here is escaping a string for use with the LIKE operator.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/tsql-like-escape-clause

Comment: Thanks recursive, I will update title to match.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To search for "%" as a literal not wildcard in a string, it needs escaped as [%].

Now, SQL Server only need 3 characters escaping: % _ [

So, create a scalar udf to wrap this:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@myString, '[', '[[]'), '_', '[_]'), '%', '[%]')
```

Because of the simplicity (aka: very limited) pattern matching in SQL, nothing more complex is needed...

Answer (score 9):

In TSQL, you can wrap the % and _ characters in brackets like so [%] [_] this tells SQL to treat them as literals.

**I have tested and verified this works in SQL Server 7.0, 2000, and 2005.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232(SQL.80).aspx

Comment: So doing "...where columnName LIKE '[%]foo%'" would actually search for any value that starts with "%foo" (the % acting as a literal, not as a wildcard? I was not aware of that.

Comment: This isn't true for string literals.

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected.  I've never seen this used in 10 years.  :-P

Comment: I've been doing SQL for 10 years too, and just YESTERDAY learned this because I couldn't get like statements to work with underscores.  So I read the docs and saw the light.

Comment: So what happens if my string has a [ in it already like: ab[%]cd and I want it to actually match exactly?

Comment: Kelsey, read the docs, they explain how to escape brackets as well.

Comment: @Kelsey - then you can define an escape charater using LIKE @text ESCPAPE '~' and your text would be ab~[~%~]cd. See my updated/corrected answer below.

Comment: +1 for the details but I have to award the answer to gbn as he included code that I could just cut and past and add.  I would like to have given you a +2 though :)

Answer (score 0):

Each character to be treated literally should be enclosed in square brackets. A right bracket is taken literally directly so don't enclose that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you parameterize your query you don't need to worry about it.

**UPDATE**

As recursive stated in the comments, % still needs to be escaped even in parameterized queries, I didn't realize linq to sql was doing it automagically when I tested.

You can use ESCAPE 'x' where x is the character you wish to be the escape character.  Linq to SQL does it like this

WHERE [Name] LIKE @searchText ESCAPE '~'

where @searchText = [some text with a~% character%]

or as others have stated it can be escaped with [%]

[view the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: This is not true.  Try it yourself.

Comment: The question in the OP is unrelated to Parameterized queries. The question is valid with or without params

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Linq to SQL does it automatically. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd sanitize the string in the front-end application rather than try and do hokey stuff in SQL to work around this.

Comment: What if you ACTUALLY need percent signs or underscores in text?

Comment: I don't want my stored proc to rely on the caller passing it cleaned data.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to modify the incoming text, you can use the "LEFT" function to create your own "STARTSWITH":

```
SELECT [Name] 
  FROM [Test] 
 WHERE @searchText = LEFT( [Name], LEN( @searchText ) )
```

(Note that you probably need to do extra work to handle the case of NULLs or empty string.)

EDIT: Removed the incorrect statement about using "LIKE" to search for "%".

Comment: It appears to be very common misconception, but you CAN escape % and _ in LIKE comparisons

Answer (score -1):

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232(SQL.80).aspx):

> **Syntax**
>
> *match_expression* [ NOT ] LIKE *pattern*
>   [ ESCAPE *escape_character* ]

Use the `ESCAPE` option like so:

```
SELECT [Name] 
  FROM [Test] 
 WHERE [Name] LIKE (REPLACE(@searchText, '%', '%%') + '%') ESCAPE '%'
```

Comment: I thought of this route but would I need to do this for %, _, [, ], and any other characters?  That seems like a lot of searching and replacing.