# Restrict user from entering search string start with wildcard using custom validator

Tags: c#, regex, search, expression, validation

I am writing a search module where i need to restrict user from entering search string start with wildcard using custom validator like

```
*apple, *?apple, ?apple, **apple, ??apple etc
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to not limit the user, but escape his text before passing it on? If you're using Regex, you could use Regex.Escape (See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) or SQL Like (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428197/how-to-escape-a-string-for-use-with-the-like-operator-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^[^*?]
```

This will match a string that doesn't begin with `*` or `?`

Answer (score 0):

What about using a validation expression like

```
^[a-zA-Z].*$
```

i.e. allowing only a letter as first character, or

```
^[^\*\?].*$
```

i.e. anything that is not a * or ? as first character.