# SQL Server T-SQL search special characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server, how to search special characters like square brackets?

I have tried using code below to search .

```
select * 
from dbo.Content
where title like '%\[TESTING(TEST)(\[]%' escape '\'.
```

I need to manually put backslash in front of all square bracket in order to get the result. Does anyone know what query/function can use to query all kind of data especially special characters.

Answer (score 1):

To search for `[` just write `[[]` 
Any special character can be escaped this way. So `%` will be `[%]`

Or maybe this suits more your question

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@myString, '[', '[[]'), '_', '[_]'), '%', '[%]')
```

[How to escape a string for use with the LIKE operator in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1428502/8113019)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for Special character  we can check for alphanumeric and then have NOT (!) to get the row where title has special characters. (WHERE title  LIKE '%[^a-z0-9 .]%' )