# SQL Server LIKE containing bracket characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, pattern-matching

I am using [SQL Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2008). I have a table with the following column:

```
sampleData (nvarchar(max))
```

The value for this column in some of these rows are lists formatted as follows:

```
["value1","value2","value3"]
```

I'm trying to write a simple query that will return all rows with lists formatted like this, by just detecting the opening bracket.

```
SELECT * from sampleTable where sampleData like '[%'
```

The above query doesn't work, because '[' is a special character. How can I escape the bracket so my query does what I want?

Comment: The canonical seems to be *[How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/)*.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

```
 ... like '[[]%'
```

You use `[ ]` to surround a special character (or range).

See the section "Using Wildcard Characters As Literals" in [SQL Server LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Note: You don't need to escape the closing bracket...

Comment: actually closing bracket `]` *should* not be escaped, else it would give wrong results

Answer (score 39):

Aside from [gbn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661125/sql-server-like-containing-bracket-characters/3661145#3661145), the other method is to use the `ESCAPE` option:

```sql
SELECT * from sampleTable where sampleData like '\[%' ESCAPE '\'
```

See the [`LIKE` Transact-SQL documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Just a further note here...

If you want to include the bracket (or other specials) within a set of characters, you only have the option of using ESCAPE (since you are already using the brackets to indicate the set).

Also you *must* specify the ESCAPE clause, since there is no default escape character (it isn't backslash by default as I first thought, coming from a C background).

E.g., if I want to pull out rows where a column contains anything outside of a set of 'acceptable' characters, for the sake of argument let's say alphanumerics... we might start with this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTest WHERE MyCol LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

So we are returning anything that has any character not in the list (due to the leading caret ^ character).

If we then want to add special characters in this set of acceptable characters, we cannot nest the brackets, so we must use an escape character, like this...

```
SELECT * FROM MyTest WHERE MyCol LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Preceding the brackets (individually) with a backslash and indicating that we are using backslash for the escape character allows us to escape them within the functioning brackets indicating the set of characters.

Comment: So we're out of luck if we're using PATINDEX?