# How do i match text excluding difference between brackets in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've an audit log table that has a series of strings like

> "Some Text[details]more text"

the pattern before and after the [details] indicates what the audit trail entry type is. The text in the bracket indicates what it is for. I want to create a query to only find the audit entries i'm after. I thought to use the following like *"Some Text[%]more text"* but it does not seem to work

When I run the below query it retrieves the expected results + more

```
select top 1000 *
from Table
where NAME like 'Some Text%'
```

When I try

```
select top 1000 *
from Table
where NAME like 'Some Text[%'
```

Nothing comes back is the

Comment: hi, are you trying to search for values in that column excluding the strings inside the open ([) and close (]) brackets?

Answer (score 1):

Brackets have a special syntactic meaning in regular expressions.  So you need to escape the bracket if you want to use it in your query:

```
select top 1000 *
from Table
where NAME like 'Some Text[[]%'
```

Special characters can be escaped by placing them inside brackets.  In this case, the opening bracket itself needs to be placed inside brackets, i.e. `[[]`

Answer (score 1):

try the t-sql code below:

```
create table dbo.tblTest (ID int IDENTITY(1, 1), strings varchar(200))

insert dbo.tblTest
select 'i have to find this text excluding [these strings inside the brackets]'
union all select '[don''t include these texts inside the brackets]. but include these!'
union all select 'why can''t i search for these, but [not these]? nothing seems to work when brackets are involved. :('

select *
from dbo.tblTest

DECLARE @stringToSearchFor VARCHAR(200) = 'nothing seems'

SELECT t.*
FROM dbo.tblTest t
    JOIN
        (SELECT nobrackets.*
        FROM
            (SELECT cleanString = REPLACE(t.strings, SUBSTRING(t.strings, CHARINDEX('[', t.strings), CHARINDEX(']', t.strings) - CHARINDEX('[', t.strings) + 1), '')
                , t.ID
            FROM dbo.tblTest t) noBrackets
        WHERE noBrackets.cleanString LIKE CONCAT('%', @stringToSearchFor, '%')) tNoBracket ON tNoBracket.ID = t.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will take sometime here in stackoverflow, a lot of post will answer your question.. Please see below.

You need to use `[ ]` bracket to surround the text with special character..

The query now look something like:

```
select top 1000 *
from Table
where NAME like '[Some Text[]%'
```

[SQL LIKE CONDITION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

[SQL Server LIKE containing bracket characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661125/sql-server-like-containing-bracket-characters)

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1000 *
from Table
where NAME like 'Some Text[[%] more text'
```

or

```
select top 1000 *
from Table
where NAME like 'Some Text![%] more text' ESCAPE '!'
```

[How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause)