# Like condition with multiple % in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I want to search for the following string in a SP. How should I go about it?

```
cal.[dbo].[GetNumberOfWorkingDays]
```

I did not get expected results when I tried

```
 '%cal.[dbo].[GetNumberOfWorkingDays]%'.
```

Does it work? : `'%cal%GetNumberOfWorkingDays%'`

Comment: Please show sample data and the queries you've tried

Comment: How did you search for it...

Comment: [ ] are special characters in LIKE command. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661125/sql-server-like-containing-bracket-characters

Answer (score 1):

Square bracket is reserved character in SQL Server `like` operator syntax, so you have to escape it:

```
like '%cal.\[dbo].\[GetNumberOfWorkingDays]%' escape '\'
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use CHARINDEX instead of LIKE. Since I am guessing this is in a where clause it would be something like this.

```
WHERE CHARINDEX('cal.[dbo].[GetNumberOfWorkingDays]', YourColumn, 0) > 0
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx