# SQL Server Like is not working with Square brackets and hyphens

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I am trying to do a like for following charecters,

> [C0-S12]ECT-PM18052

As metnioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661125/sql-server-like-containing-bracket-characters) I tried following query,

```
 WHERE Barcode LIKE '[[C0-S12]%'
```

and this returns everything. It completely ignores the left side which is constant. For example I am getting back following results back.

> [C0-S12]ECT-PM18052
>   [C0-S8]ECT-PM18052
>   [C0-B14]ECT-PM18052
>   [C0-S17]ECT-PM18052
>   [C0-B3]ECT-PM18052
>   [C0-S7]ECT-PM18052
>   [C0-B12]ECT-PM18052

I have also tried following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause) and escaped using `'/ /`'.

```
  WHERE Barcode LIKE '\[C0-S12%\'
```

and this does not return anything atll.

Comment: What are you trying to match and not match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version works:

```
WHERE Barcode LIKE '$[C0-S12]%' ESCAPE '$'
```

I notice that the `\` escape doesn't work on Rextester.  It *should* work, but it doesn't.