# mssql patindex for ] symbol

Tags: sql-server, character, symbols, patindex

How to specify ] symbol inside character class (MS SQL SERVER PATINDEX function)?

```
'%["[]%' - for starting bracket - it works
'%["]]%' - for ending - it does not
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server LIKE containing bracket characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661125/sql-server-like-containing-bracket-characters)

Comment: PATINDEX can not be used with ESCAPE keyword as it can with LIKE.

Comment: You're right. Does [this DBA.SE Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206481/matching-a-closing-square-bracket-with-patindex-using-the-wildcard) about closing square bracket help? You might find some workaround there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is no way to  properly escape closing bracket (]) in PATINDEX. ] alone can be [written verbatim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms187489(v=sql.90)#searching-for-wildcard-characters), but cannot be included in the character set.

However, according to [this DBA.SE question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206481/matching-a-closing-square-bracket-with-patindex-using-the-wildcard), there are some workaround (see the linked article for the full example):

1. [Specify character range that contains ]. (note that this will match unwanted characters)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206482/79747)

```sql
PATINDEX('%[[-^{}:,]%' COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN2, MyJSONString)
```

2. [Apply REPLACE before match.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206488/79747)

```sql
PATINDEX('%[[' + CHAR(174) + '@]%', REPLACE(@test,']',CHAR(174)))
```

3. [Use PATINDEX twice: one for ], and the other for the rest of characters.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/206493/79747)

```sql
(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[[{}:,]%', d.ResponseJSON), 0), NULLIF(PATINDEX('%]%', d.ResponseJSON), 0)))
```

Comment: No. 1 seems be the one i am looking for.
No. 2 cannot be as a workaround. In JSON could be symbol ] as text, not as array closing bracket. No. 3 searches two times.

Answer (score 0):

After testing different options, this seemed to work as expected. Give it a try.

```
PATINDEX('%[^]]%', 'test[test]') +1
```

The "+1" is added because in every test I performed it always stopped one character before the ending bracket "]", this makes sure to capture open and closing positions.

Give it a try, let me know what you think.