# delete a record contains `%`

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to delete a record which contains `%` sign, for example:

> white%House, Den%mark, bengali%20Tiger, White%202.

I have this query but it doesn't work for me.

```
delete from nail where name like '%[%]%'
```

I am using C# and Access.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/tsql-like-escape-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me native in MS Access

```
DELETE foo.foo1
FROM foo
WHERE (((foo.foo1) ALike "%[%]%"));
```

Maybe it's the double quotes instead of the apostrophes.

Perhaps in C# you need to do something like

```
bar = "DELETE foo.foo1 FROM foo WHERE (((foo.foo1) ALike \"%[%]%\"));";
```

Comment: delete from thumbnail t  where (((t.name) ALike \"%[%]%\")), this is how i did it and still it is not working;

Comment: What does it complain about? The "alike"? Have you tried flipping it back to "like"?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some confusion going on, so here is a complete code example that works for me:

```
using ( var conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\users\john\desktop\Database11.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"))
{
     conn.Open();
     OleDbCommand cmd = 
         new OleDbCommand("DELETE FROM TABLE1 where [name] like '%[%]%'", conn);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     cmd.Dispose();
     conn.Close();
}
```

Note that you are using "name" as one of your fields, which is a reserved word, so you need to escape it inside of brackets.  The same goes for the %, since it is the wildcard character that is used by OLEDb.

Comment: They support both. `%` is the "official" SQL [wildcard character](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp).

Comment: i am trying it like this and its not working delete from thumbnail  where (((name) ALike \"%[%]%\"))

Comment: I modified the code example to be a full example and changed it to use the correct wildcard values, based on Uwe's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `InStr()` to find if the name contains %

```
where InStr(name, '%') > 0
```

Comment: It may work for the specific situation, but it doesn't generalise well. The @safi really is looking for how to escape the % character.

Comment: @CodeSlave, I really don't know Access... I would like to understand why `ALike "%[%]%"` is better than `InStr(name, '%')`, if you don't mind...

Comment: No problem. Lets say you wanted to delete all row starting with `foo%`; if you were to do the same trick: `InStr(name 'foo%'') > 0`, you could be deleting other rows: `barfoo%` and `yaddahfoo%`. With `Like "foo[%]%"` you only delete `foo%`, `foo%bar`, `foo%foo`, etc.  Escaping the % properly lets you continue to use the `Like` condition (ALike in this case seems to be Access/Jet's ANSI-92 version of the Like condition). Your method works, but kind of kludgey.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake:

Within MS Access running in its default SQL mode (ANSI 89), you would use:

```
  Like "*%*"
```

Likewise, if you're using DAO to execute the SQL, you'd use that.

You only run into problems here when running in ANSI 92 mode, which is available within Access only if you have ANSI 92 turned on, or if you're using ADO, or if you use `ALIKE` instead of `LIKE`. In that case, you have to use the more standard `%` wildcard. If you're running within Access or using DAO, you can use `ALIKE` to allow you to use the `%` wildcard:

ALike "%[%]%"

But if you're running Access in SQL 92 mode, you don't need `ALIKE` at all, you can just use `LIKE` (but I would never recommend running Access in SQL 92 mode, as it breaks a number of things within Access).

If you're using ADO/OLEDB to execute the SQL, your only option is SQL 92 mode, and you should be able to use either `ALike "%[%]%"` or Like `"%[%]%"`. I don't know whether the double quotes make a difference or not, though. In my tests using ADO within Access, it didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
delete from nail where name like '%[[%]%'
```