# Parameterized LIKE clause in SQL statement using Dapper

Tags: sql, dapper

I want to perform the following query using Dapper, which currently doesn't return expected results (I think it must be treating the @pName param as literal text within the single quotes?):

```
var q = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name LIKE '@pName%'";
```

@pName is the param I assign a value to upon executing the query.

Things work if I just build the SQL like:

```
var q = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name LIKE '" + name + "%'";
```

.. but I would prefer to use a param if possible.

I am executing the query using the following code:

```
o = _cn.Query<User>(q, new { pName = new DbString { Value = name, IsFixedLength = false, Length = 25, IsAnsi = true } }).ToList();
```

How do I got about this using Dapper?

Comment: make sure you remember to escape your like clause (see comment on answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Name LIKE @pName + '%'
```

Comment: Make sure you escape your like clause though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/tsql-like-escape-clause

Comment: Thanks Sam. I wasn't familiar with this so will add it.

Comment: Buggered if I know. Someone else did that as an edit. I rolled it back.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add here another possible solution:

```
var results = cn.Query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE @value", new { value = value + "%" });
```

The wildcard is inside the string var itself, and then we reference that var in the SQL. Applies to any wildcard pattern you want.