# sql server: need to escape [?

Tags: sql, sql-server, escaping

I need to escape [ in an sql query for SQL Server

```
select * from sometable where name like '[something]';
```

I actually am looking for a [ before something and I don't want it to act like a wildcard.  I tried :

```
select * from sometable where name like ''[something]';
```

But get error message from this:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'something'.
>   Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string ';

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
select * from sometable where name like '[[]something[]]';
```

you may use as well:

```
select * from sometable where name like '\[something\]' escape '\';
```

Described in [LIKE (Transact-SQL) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx).

Comment: Yes!!  That worked!!  Thank you very much for all the comments!!

Answer (score 4):

Embed the `[` in `[]`

```
declare @T table
(
  name varchar(20)
)

insert into @T values
('abc'),
('[abc')

select *
from @T 
where name like '[[]a%'
```

Result:

```
name
--------------------
[abc
```

Have a look here at what you can do in the `like` expression. [LIKE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

Comment: It might help to point out that it's using regular expressions, so the [...] denote an acceptable character set. And that's how/why this solution works.

Comment: @weston - Updated the answer with a link to where you can read all about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little sample code.  You need to embed the `[` within `[]`:

```
SELECT FirstName 
  FROM (SELECT '[Test]' AS FirstName) as t 
 WHERE FirstName LIKE '[[]%'
```