# Unable to match square bracket [ character in SQL

Tags: sql, string-matching

I am trying to select records that start with this string pattern 'Dear [User Name]'. The following where clause:

```
where Message like 'Dear [UserName]%'
```

returns nothing.
What is the problem and what is the solution?

Note 1: the field [Message] DOES start with this text.
Note 2: the type of field [Message] is text, but the same problme happens with varchar fields.

Comment: There is a question already posted. See this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984380/sql-server-need-to-escape

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2. And yes, this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984380/sql-server-need-to-escape, so I will close it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
 where Message like 'Dear \[User Name\]' escape '\';
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. Even if you do not escape the ] it still works.

Answer (score 2):

The [] is a wild card character matching operator which "Matches any single character within the specified range or set that is specified between the brackets."
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179884.aspx

To get a correct match you can write:

```
where Message like 'Dear [[]User Name]%'
```