# Escape square brackets in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, escaping, dynamic-sql

I read [this post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/) about putting column name and table name as variables.
I want square brackets wrapping column name and table name. I saw some people do this:

```
@sql = 'SELECT [' + @column_name + '] FROM ...'
```

I tried to put square brackets into the variable like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[find_most_frequent] 
    @table_in VARCHAR,
    @col_2 VARCHAR 
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);

    SET @sql =
--start of code
'SELECT' +
        @col_2 +
    ' FROM ' + @table_in +
' GO'
--end of code    
    print @sql
    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
END 
GO

EXEC [dbo].[find_most_frequent]
        @table_in = '[[]dbo].[[]t1]'
        ,@col_2 = '[[]c1]' 
GO
```

I have used [[] to escape square brackets, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984380/sql-server-need-to-escape). But it does work, @sql is

```
SELECT[ FROM [ GO
```

Can somebody help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

varchar [ ( n | max ) ]

When n is not specified in a data definition or variable declaration statement, the default length is 1.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms176089.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the quoting of object names, there is a function in SQL Server to do exactly that: [quotename()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).

Be careful, though, as the function has a nasty habit of returning `NULL` when its input exceeds 128 characters. It doesn't happen when you quote object and / or column names, but might fire up in other cases.