# How do you alter a SQL Server credential that contains square brackets?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, credentials

I want to alter a credential on my SQL Server install.  It was auto-generated when I set up a replication publication to be used with the replication transaction log reader proxy.  Apparently it was generated with square brackets as part of its name because when I select from `sys.credentials`, its entry's name is `[REPL][BACP\jeremy][DAVEG1525-162-AssessmentSystemLiveTest-1]`.

How can I alter its credential?  I tried this:

```
ALTER CREDENTIAL [REPL][BACP\jeremy][DAVEG1525-162-AssessmentSystemLiveTest-1] WITH IDENTITY = N'BACP\jeremy', SECRET = N'NewPasswordHere'
```

However it says that this is incorrect syntax.  The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187923.aspx) for `ALTER CREDENTIAL` only gives examples for credentials whose name doesn't contain square brackets.  How can I alter this credential?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually worked:

```
ALTER CREDENTIAL [[REPL]][BACP\jeremy]][DAVEG1525-162-AssessmentSystemLiveTest-1]]] WITH IDENTITY = N'BACP\jeremy', SECRET = N'NewPasswordHere'
```

Escaping square brackets in SQL Server is not nice.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape [] brackets as shown in this post:

[How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause)

Hopefully that will point you in the right direction.