# sql select value with square bracket in Like clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple select query:

```
Select * from ABC
where title like N'%[text] xxxxx%'   => return nothing.

Select * from ABC
where title like N'%xxxxx%'  => correct record   '[text] xxxx'
```

My table has some records with content contains [xxx] ..... and i have to compare them with other content from source outside the database, and the content from the source also may contains square bracket.

e.g: i could have thousands of titles from othersource to compare:

- [text] content
- content

2 formats, just don't know how to compare with the title in Database because i dont know beforehand its structure.

How can I pass in a content that possible contains a square bracket and still get the correct result ?

Comment: '[text] xxxx' has 4 'x', obviously it doesn't match N'%[text] xxxxx%' which has 5 'x', is it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Searching with special characters***](http://web.archive.org/web/20150519072547/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com:80/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html)

```
SELECT * 
FROM ABC
WHERE title LIKE N'%\[text] xxxxx%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use it like below

```
Select * from ABC 
where title like N'%[[]text] xxxxx%'
```

check this related SO thread here [How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause)

Comment: yes i know these, but the text is unknown, it could be anything, and the bracket could be in any where in the like clause.

Comment: @namvo, yes it could be anywhere but the point here is it needs to be escaped likewise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [] to surround a special character (or range). So if you want your search cantains any of the brackets, just use "[[]" instead of "[" and "[]]" instead of "]" in your where clause.

```
Select * from ABC
where title like N'%[[]text[]] xxxxx%'
```