# SQL column names and quotename

Tags: sql

I have a query that should be ignoring my applications system columns, I can't explain why it's not detecting the following column as a system column. A system column starts with DW_ and could contain a space, hence the use of quotename.

```
 DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(max)

 set @columnName = Quotename('DW_ID')

 print @columnName

 IF (@columnName LIKE 'DW_%')
    print 'system column'
 else
    print 'non system column'
```

I would expect the above query  to tell me it's a system column but it tells me it's a non system column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, [`Quotename`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) adds brackets to `DW_ID`, which makes that `DW_%` will never match on `[DW_ID]`.

Second, you should match on the brackets too. Since brackets have a special meaning in a `like` you [need to escape them](https://stackoverflow.com/q/439495/993547):

```
DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(max)

set @columnName = Quotename('DW_ID')
-- @columnName is [DW_ID] now

print @columnName

IF (@columnName LIKE '[[]DW_%]')
   print 'system column'
else
   print 'non system column'
```

Comment: This doesn't print out system column - it prints out non system column

Comment: You can also use another character in quotename. QUOTENAME('DW_ID', '<') will give you '<DW_ID>' this could make the like comparison a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

`quotename()` adds square braces:

```
select Quotename('DW_ID')

[DW_ID]
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/153) is a little SQL Fiddle.

So you would want to include these in your pattern matching.  Something like:

```
IF (@columnName LIKE '[[]DW_%]')
```

Comment: This doesn't print out system column - it prints out non system column.

Comment: @d347hm4n . . . This followed the logic in the question, before the question was modified.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I don't see the question updated in the mean-time. Never mind, I fixed the code issue. If you want to revert, feel free.