# How to escape square brackets in SSIS - Derived Column Regex?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

Some of my source columns has a square bracket (Due to CSV import) **e.g. TableID1.[column]**.

When I try to perform transformation for those columns in SSIS (using Derived Column component), I am receiving the below error:

> Error at DFT [Derived Column 1 [478]]: Attempt to parse the expression
>   "[TableID1.[Column1]]" failed.  The token "[" at line number "0",
>   character number "0" was not recognized. The expression cannot be
>   parsed because it contains invalid elements at the location specified.

Which I believe is complaining about the Square bracket ("[") that comes as a part of column name. I believe it is interfering with its (Derived Columns') native Regex processing which also uses "[  ]"

How can I escape these square brackets in SSIS ?

**P.S.** I understand changing the source column name using an alias is an option. But it is not efficient in my case where I am dealing with 50+ columns with similar format.

Comment: Do you have column name of single word or multiple? If it is single then easily you can get rid of brackets..

Comment: @AmneshGoel: The column names are usually multiple words with spaces and special characters in it - something like "Address 1: Address Type"

Comment: Then you cannot skip that..

Comment: Did you try `'\'`?  .. and check this [out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause)

Comment: @AmneshGoel: Yep. I tried that. Doesn't work.