# How can I make LIKE match a number or empty string inside square brackets in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to have a `LIKE` clause with one character number or an empty string?

I have a field in which I will write a `LIKE` clause (as a string). I will apply it later with an expression in the `WHERE` clause: `... LIKE tableX.FormatField ...`. It must contain a number (a single character or an empty string).

Something like `[0-9 ]`. Where the space bar inside square brackets means an empty string.

I have a table in which I have a configuration for parameters - `TblParam` with field `DataFormat`. I have to validate a value from another table, `TblValue`, with field `ValueToCheck`. The validation is made by a query. The part for the validation looks like:

`... WHERE TblValue.ValueToCheck LIKE TblParam.DataFormat ...`

For the configuration value, I need an expression for one numeric character or an empty string. Something like `[0-9'']`. Because of the automatic nature of the check, I need a single expression (without `AND` OR `OR` operators) which can fit the query (see the example above). The same check is valid for other types of the checks, so I have to fit my check engine.

I am almost sure that I can not use `[0-9'']`, but is there another suitable solution?

Actually, I have difficulty to validate a version string: `1.0.1.2` or `1.0.2`. It can contain 2-3 dots (`.`) and numbers.

Comment: like '[0-9 ]' works here.  Maybe I'm not understanding the q.

Comment: Did you like try?   Space is not the same as empty string.

Comment: I just try to illustrate what kind of expression I need @Frisbee. I need something like `[0-9'']` (single digit or empty string) but I know this will not work.

Comment: See my answer - it won't work that way.  '' is null

Comment: Slightly related (not a duplicate): *[How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure it is not possible, as '' is not even a character.

*select ascii('');* returns *null*.

'' = ' '; is true

'' is null;  is false

If you want exactly 0-9 '' (and not ' '), then you do to something like this (in a more efficient way than *like*):

```
where col in ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','9','0') or (col = '' and DATALENGTH(col) = 0)
```

Comment: Yes, but my construction is `LIKE TblParam.DataFormat `. Your answer is ok, but I can not fit. In that case I will need several column - I try to find some common pattern for checking. If filter becomes very complex - it will be of no use.

Comment: Want and get are not the same thing.  '' is null - it is not a character

Comment: I agree - empty sting is not a character. I just check if there is a solution, even I think there is not - in construct like that.

Answer (score 1):

That's a tricky one... As far as I can tell, there isn't a way to do it with only one *like* clause. You need to do `like '[0-9]' OR like ''`.

You could accomplish this by having a second column in your `TableX`. That indicates either a second pattern, or whether or not to include blanks.

Comment: You understand properly. I suppose that there is no option, but I decided to ask just in case I don't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand your question, you need something that catches an empty string. Try to use the nullif() function:

```
create table t1 (a nvarchar(1))
insert t1(a) values('')
insert t1(a) values('1')
insert t1(a) values('2')
insert t1(a) values('a')
-- must select first three 
select a from t1 where a like '[0-9]' or nullif(a,'') is null
```

It returns exactly three records: '', '1' and '2'.

A more convenient method with only one range clause is:

```
 select a from t1 where isnull(nullif(a,''),0) like '[0-9]'
```

Comment: I like your updated construct and I vote up. I need single construct so this is not answer I need, but your where clause is good from my point of view.