# Search keyword with LIKE %[keyword]%

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have a `TransactionDetails` table with `TransactionId`, `TransactionDetail` columns, those are used to track all the transactions within the application.

The sample records of the TransactionDetail are:

```
[Blah][Log] 20 Records Inserted
[Blah][Exception] Fails on INSERT INTO
[Blah][Error] Authentication Fails Logged
[Blah][Warning] Null value is eliminated by an aggregate
[Blah][Log] 10 Records Deleted
```

I want to filter the TransactionDetail columns having the **[Log]** only *(The **Log, Logged** keyword also exist in the other rows)*. The search query with `[]` consider as regular expression pattern. How can I skip that and get the required details only.

I have tried the `\` escape character in front of the `[`, `]`, but it doesn't return any result.

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionDetails
WHERE TransactionDetail LIKE '%\[Log\]%'
```

Expected result:

```
[Blah][Log] 20 Records Inserted
[Blah][Log] 10 Records Deleted
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d69f3d/1

Comment: How many different Tags can you have?  Why not have a seperate column with a key to a table that stores 1, [Log] - 2, [Exception] - 3, [Error] - 4,[Warning] etc... then just join.  It would be WAY faster to pull out of the DB saying where keyword = 1 with a left join to get the word log

Comment: Try `LIKE '%#[Log#]%' escape '#'`.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause

Comment: @jarlh: This escape is working.

Comment: @jarlh **]** does not need escaping

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, thanks for the info. (As a non-MS SQL guy it's hard to remember all product specific details...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape SQL wildcard characters by putting them in the group, i.e.:

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionDetails
WHERE TransactionDetail LIKE '%[[]Log]%'
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by **jarlh** in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293531/search-keyword-with-like-keyword#comment58296844_35293531) the [ESCAPE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms179859.aspx) option also works:

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionDetails
WHERE TransactionDetail LIKE '%#[Log#]%' ESCAPE '#'
```

**Working Demo:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d69f3d/37

Update: As per the reply by **t-clausen.dk** in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35293531/search-keyword-with-like-keyword?noredirect=1#comment58298150_35293531), the escape_character is not required for the `]`. So the code below also works.

```
SELECT *
FROM TransactionDetails
WHERE TransactionDetail LIKE '%#[Log]%' ESCAPE '#'
```