# T-SQL LIKE with escaped characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, escaping, sql-like

To match all records with an `nvarchar` column that contains substring `Type [B]`

for example : `Owner [C] Type [B] Subtype [X]`

the following works: `LIKE '%Type [[]B[]]%'`

But it's rather confusing syntax.

Is there a better alternative ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ESCAPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) option.

The query will be `LIKE '%Type #[B]%' ESCAPE '#'`

Please find the working query with sample data:

```
DECLARE @TextTable TABLE (String NVARCHAR (500));
INSERT INTO @TextTable(String) SELECT ('Owner [C] Type [B] Subtype [X]');
INSERT INTO @TextTable(String) VALUES ('Owner [C] Type [B Subtype [X]');
INSERT INTO @TextTable(String) VALUES ('Owner [C] Type B Subtype [X]');

SELECT *
FROM @TextTable
WHERE String LIKE '%Type #[B]%' ESCAPE '#'
```

[**Working demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d5697aee6a76a280737c5e41f29c5e1f)

Comment: Also please refer this post: [Search keyword with LIKE %keyword%](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35293531/2451726)

Comment: It's only necessary to escape the open square-bracket `[` but not the close square-bracket `]` ?

Comment: @baltostar Yes, `]` does not need escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `ESCAPE` and define your custom escape character:

```
select *
from   (select 'Owner [C] Type [B] Subtype [X]' as field) as t
where   
   t.field LIKE '%Type \[B]%' ESCAPE '\' --can be any char
   --t.field LIKE '%Type .[B]%' ESCAPE '.'
```

Comment: It's only necessary to escape the open square-bracket `[` but not the close square-bracket `]` ?