# Square ([]) brackets not being recognized in text column of sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column in a SQL table that contains `json` lists as text.

I want to find all the rows that have `[7]` in the column.  So I have something like the following

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl1 WHERE col2 LIKE '[7]'
```

However this comes back with nothing (though I can see rows when I inspec the table that have that in the field).

Stranger still, if I try editing the query to the following

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl1 WHERE col2 LIKE '%[7]%'
```

It will find the rows that have `[7]`, but it will also get rows that clearly (I think) violate that pattern, i.e. rows that have `[1,7]`

Is the square bracket something special that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes.. They are are form of quoting. See this for your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause

Comment: also, using `LIKE`  without wildcards is almost the same as using `=`

Comment: @AaronD thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM tbl1 
WHERE col2 LIKE  '%\[7]%' ESCAPE '\'
```

Comment: You only need to escape the opening bracket, the closing bracket is implied `'%\[7]%' ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: @AaronD well they say everyday is a school day , I did not know this :) Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: I've learned from one (many) of your answers.  Happy to pass on this small bit.