# How can I perform a LIKE query with a square bracket in the string?

Tags: mysql

I would like to perform this query in MYSQL, but the square bracket kills it, assuming that square brackets are reserved?:

```
select * from policy_data where PolicyData like '%gross_total] => .%'
```

I'm querying some stored json data, so I'm not sure what my options are! I've tried using  back slash in front of it.

```
like '%gross_total\]%'
```

I've also tried a replace to no avail:

```
select * from policy_data where replace(PolicyData, "]", "") like '%gross_total => .%'
```

Comment: That would be the case for a regex search but is not the case for a LIKE.  Do you mean SQL Server? If so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause

Comment: Your google search string is `msql escape characters`.

Comment: What does "but of course the square bracket kills it" mean? The bracket has no special meaning in a MySQL LIKE pattern, so it should work fine and the query should get you all rows where PolicyData contains the string 'gross_total] => .%'.

Comment: Arh shoot! I was looking at how my array looked in a <pre> output on the page, not how it was stored in JSON in the table :'-(. All I needed to do was: '%gross_total":"."%' - Thank you for helping me spot it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to escape it ?

```
select * from policy_data where PolicyData like '%gross_total] \=> .%'
```

Comment: This returns results: like '%gross_total%' - this does not like '%gross_total\]%'

Comment: Can you provide more info ? I tried to run the query and it works for me. I don't get any sql errors.