# How can I use SQL's LIKE command with its own special characters?

Tags: sql, string, mathematical-expressions

I use Sybase Transact SQL with the very useful LIKE command, so to ensure that your string contains a number you simply need use:

```
WHERE @test LIKE "%[0-9]%"
```

Alternatively, to ensure that your list does not contain a number you can use:

```
WHERE @test LIKE "%[^0-9]%"
```

What test would I use to ensure that my string does not contain any of the basic mathematical functions (+, -, *, / and ^ for powers of) please? Is it a question of using square brackets in my square brackets?

Comment: If it's TSQL, it's a dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause

Comment: use `ESCAPE` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where   @test not like '%[+=!*%(){}^-]%'
```

Comment: Now that makes sense! Put the '-' at the end so it isn't a range and the '^' so it isn't at the beginning. Actually perfectly sensible - thank you.