# Incorrect result returned by SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-like

The below query is returning all data instead of showing the records which consists [3428] in ApprovedByNewTExt column.

```
select * from 
    (
        Select Rec_Num, 
            COALESCE(AppByENo6,AppByENo5,AppByENo4,AppByENo3,AppByENo2,AppByENo1)
            As 'ApprovedByNewTExt' 
        FROM MyTable
    ) 
as output
where ApprovedByNewTExt like '%[3428]%'
```

Spent more time in identifying the issue but failed to fix.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `mysql` <> `sql-server` <> `sqllite`. I have removed the conflicting tags for you, however, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50059544/edit) your question and tag **only** the relevant RDBMS.

Comment: Do you intend search to include square brackets [] ?

Comment: @P.Salmon, Yes my data consist square brackets between the numbers.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, B'cos my data includes the numbers with brackets and I would like it to search it with brackets.  I have not used brackets as wild card.  Consider the brackets as text character.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, SQL Server 2014

Comment: @Sixthsense https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you're searching for.

Right now you search for any row that contains a 3, 4, 2 or 8

If you want to search for "3428" then drop the [ and ]

If you want to search for "[3428]" then you need to escape the [ and ], see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause)

Comment: Joakim Danielson, This is what I am looking for "[3428]"  which should be checked inside the column text.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the question was tagged with Sql Server when I answered it, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Sixthsense, so did you try with escaping the [ and ] then as in the link?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using MS SQL Server you'll need to escape the square brackets:

```
select *
from 
(
  Select Rec_Num, 
  COALESCE(AppByENo6,AppByENo5,AppByENo4,AppByENo3,AppByENo2,AppByENo1) As 'ApprovedByNewText' 
  FROM MyTable
) as output
where ApprovedByNewText like '%\[3428]%' escape '\'
```

- SQL Fiddle Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6576d/1
- Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause

p.s. Just realised that [@JoakimDanielson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50059691/361842) already linked to a similar answer; so if this resolves your issue, please give him the "right answer" vote.  Leaving this answer in place as it has runnable code.

Comment: Tried your suggestion and getting only one record.  But it should show 25 records.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?  I suspect there's a reason the records not returned aren't being pulled back, but can't say what that is without seeing the data...

Comment: Oh God!  Real time development made me this error.  When I first checked the database there was 25 records.  Now it consist only 1 record since the user moved that records.  Thanks a lot for your time.  Its my mistake in doing development in real time DB.

Comment: @Sixthsense great news :).  BTW, please can you give JoakimDanielson's answer the accepted answer vote instead of mine; as he beat me to this answer by a good 30 mins, so deserves the points.  Thank-you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Dont use the sqaure brackets in `where ApprovedByNewTExt like '%3428%'`

Comment: When i use it in that way I am getting only one record.  But there is 25 records with that text.

Comment: that must be due to some error in the query, but for the like statement this is the correct syntax.

Comment: give some more detail and i'll look up into it then