# Search for all Records which contain the word size and end with a?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a series of questions in a table, I want all the records that contain the word size and must end with a "?" in the record.  When I do a SQL, the "?" is treated as a special character but I want it treated it as a normal character, how do I escape it.  I've looked on the internet and StackOverflow but the only questions explain that "?" is a wild card which I don't want it to be.

```
select * from Questions where QuestionText like '%Size%?'
```

So it returns for example...  Its simplistic but you get the idea hopefully.

```
What is the size of france?
```

But doesn't return

```
What is the size of france.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I escape square brackets in a LIKE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439495/how-can-i-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the behavior is documented: [Pattern Matching with the ESCAPE Clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To escape the special meaning of any special character, just enclose it in square brackets.

```
Select * from Questions where QuestionText like '%Size%[?]'
```